# Oracle error Statement Ignored in trigger

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, arcgis

While trying to create a trigger that updates another table, the following error gives on several lines, the error seems at random lines and doesn't really help, but is the first time I try to use PL/SQL inside a trigger.

Error(9,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Error(9,21): PLS-00548:

Trigger code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TORRE_T
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON TORRES
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    FUSO_T VARCHAR(50 CHAR);
    X_TORRES_UTM NUMBER;
    Y_TORRES_UTM NUMBER;
    X_TORRES NUMBER;
    Y_TORRES NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FUSO_T := :NEW.FUSO_UTM;
    X_TORRES := sde.st_x(:NEW.shape);
    Y_TORRES := sde.st_Y(:NEW.shape);
    IF INSERTING THEN
        IF FUSO_T = '20S' THEN
            X_TORRES_UTM := sde.st_x(sde.st_transform(:NEW.shape, 31980));
            Y_TORRES_UTM := sde.st_Y(sde.st_transform(:NEW.shape, 31980));
        ELSIF FUSO_T = '21S' THEN
            X_TORRES_UTM := sde.st_x(sde.st_transform(:NEW.shape, 31981));
            Y_TORRES_UTM := sde.st_Y(sde.st_transform(:NEW.shape, 31981));
        ELSIF FUSO_T = '22S' THEN
            X_TORRES_UTM := sde.st_x(sde.st_transform(:NEW.shape, 31982));
            Y_TORRES_UTM := sde.st_Y(sde.st_transform(:NEW.shape, 31982));
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO COORDTORRES(OBJECTID, GEOCODIGO, LONGITUDEDEC, LATITUDEDEC, LONGITUDEGMS, LATITUDEGMS, COORDXUTM, COORDYUTM, FUSOUTM)
            VALUES(
                :NEW.OBJECTID, 
                :NEW.CODIGO,
                X_TORRES,
                Y_TORRES,
                replace(abs(trunc(X_TORRES))||'°'||to_char(trunc((abs(X_TORRES) - abs(trunc(X_TORRES)))*60), '00')||'''' || to_char((((abs(X_TORRES) - abs(trunc(X_TORRES)))*60) - trunc(((abs(X_TORRES) - abs(trunc(X_TORRES)))*60))) * 60, '00.00') || '"' || 'W', ' '),
                replace(abs(trunc(Y_TORRES))||'°'||to_char(trunc((abs(Y_TORRES) - abs(trunc(Y_TORRES)))*60), '00')||'''' || to_char((((abs(Y_TORRES) - abs(trunc(Y_TORRES)))*60) - trunc(((abs(Y_TORRES) - abs(trunc(Y_TORRES)))*60))) * 60, '00.00') || '"' || 'N', ' '),
                X_TORRES_UTM,
                Y_TORRES_UTM,
                FUSO_T
              );
    END IF;
END;
```

Full error stack on SQLDeveloper :

```
Error(9,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(9,21): PLS-00548: Invalid use of operator
Error(10,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(10,21): PLS-00548: Invalid use of operator
Error(13,13): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(13,33): PLS-00548: Invalid use of operator
Error(14,13): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(14,33): PLS-00548: Invalid use of operator
Error(16,13): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(16,33): PLS-00548: Invalid use of operator
Error(17,13): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(17,33): PLS-00548: Invalid use of operator
Error(19,13): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(19,33): PLS-00548: Invalid use of operator
Error(20,13): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(20,33): PLS-00548: Invalid use of operator.
```

Comment: The error line number is pointing to the 9th line of the PL/SQL section - not the overall statement, which is slightly confusing. That means it's referring to `X_TORRES := sde.st_x(:NEW.shape);`, but not sure why you'd get that error from the 21st character of that line, which seems to be the start of `st_x`. How is `sde` defined? [edit: I see - it's ArcGIS?) And is that the full error stack you get?

Comment: @Alex It seems like a third party package.

Comment: @AlexPoole sde is a external library that has always worked for us, the error at line 9 character 21 seems to be the BEGIN statement

Comment: No, see previous comment. Triggers are a bit weird, as they mix the SQL-level `create` statement with a PL/SQL block. In your trigger the PL/SQL errors see `DECLARE` as line 1, so `BEGIN` is line 7. The PL/SQL compiler effectively doesn't see or count anything before the PL/SQL code. The errors are being reported on the pairs of lines that call `st_x` and `st_y`. (Unfortunately I can't see why...)

Comment: @AlexPoole This is the first time we try to use the sde library in a trigger, do you know if it needs to be declared beforehand or something like that?

Comment: No, it should work the same as in any other named PL/SQL block. (Named because permissions are handled differently to anonymous blocks). Do you have a schema or any other objects called SDE; with a user-created operator call `st_x`? Seems unlikely, but that's the only way I can see you;d get that error.

Comment: ... or a user-defined operator called just `sde`, which seems to cause the same error? Either of those would imply a scope issue too I think, and/or privileges on the real SDE package being granted through a role. Do you normally use the package from anonymous PL/SQL blocks, or packages/stored procedures, and is it installed in the same schema you're creating the trigger in?